# Kubeflow dashboard returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, microk8s

I have a problem with Kubeflow Dashboard. Until now I could connect to the dashboard without problems, but after a restart of the PC it gives me forbidden when I try to connect from my browser to **http://10.64.140.43.nip.io** (this is the url received after kubeflow was enabled).

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machine where I installed **microk8s 1.20.10** following the steps from this link: **https://microk8s.io/docs** and then enabled **kubeflow(v1.2) addon**. When I check kubeflow pods I can see that dex-auth pod sometimes is crashing with the following error:
**"failed to list custom resource authcodes.dex.coreos.com, attempting to create: Get "https://[10.152.183.1]:443/apis/dex.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/kubeflow/authcodes": dial tcp 10.152.183.1:443: connect: connection refused"**

After a few restarts of dex-auth deployment the pod is successfully Running, but still the dashborad is not working. It's not the first time I encounter this issue and the only solution I could find was to reinstall microk8s again.

I also installed: ****Knative v0.24**, **Istio for Knative v0.24, KFServing v0.5**** for model prediction and from what I can see, after the restart the kubeflow dashboard can be accesed from this url: **http://10.64.140.44.nip.io**, but it shows me only the main page, when I try to navigate to experiments, runs or pipelines pages this message appears: **no healthy upstream**.

I am new to kubernetes and kubeflow so any help or any suggestion as to what I might do to solve this problem is welcome. Thanks.